# on WAMPSERVER in wordpressp theme show css changes after shutdown my Computer

Tags: css, wordpress

i have WORDPRESS theme on wampserver(local server)
when i change or add some properties to my style.css for example when i change the background on change font-size the changes don't appear after refreshing the theme. after shutting down my COMPUTER the changes appear correctly.

i must do anything until show changes in style.css without shutting down?

Comment: Try a hard refresh of the page (CTRL and F5)

Comment: thank you my problem it is solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is to use the private window of chrome.

Comment: thank you for reply but ctrl+f5 it is good for solving my problem

Comment: yes by using the private window it is solve my problem but now i use the CTRL+F5 it is the best soution